# TableView How to get background color of the columns

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

In Swing, `JTable.getTableHeader().getBackground()` produces Color (that contains the color of the column header).

Is there an equivalent in Javafx for TableView?

Comment: Well, in `JavaFX` you usually style your window using `CSS`. To style the header of a `TableView`, you could do the following: `.table-view .column-header{ -fx-background-color: red; }`. You could play around with the various `CSS` selector methods to retrieve the styling.

Comment: Not that simple. It's not that simple in javafx. A background may not simply ba a color. Images and gradients can be used too. Furthermore there are different sources. @Jaims How does getting a color by setting it work?????

Comment: @fabian I just said that's how the `TableHeader` *could* be styled. And therefore you could use `CSS` selector methods such as `getCssMetaData()` or `getStyle()`. It was a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for your responses. As Fabian says, maybe is not simple in javafx. I was looking for getCssMetaData but a cant get the Background color of the columns of a TableView. In Swing I had a method for generate excel with Apache POI with JTable as parameter, I simply send anyone JTable and i generate excel with colors of the JTable. In Javafx I couldn't do that

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an equivalent in Javafx for TableView?

Unfortunately JavaFX doesn't offer a built in method equivalent to `getTableHeader().getBackground()`

---

However..... you can still access it via the notorious [node lookup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup-java.lang.String-)

Using this method you can obtain different `Region`'s of the `TableView`, which allows you to manipulate them.

It is important to note here, that the lookup will return null if the CSS hasn't been applied to the `Scene` yet, which doesn't usually happen until it is rendered. There are workarounds for this, but they aren't all guarantees, such as:

- Forcibly  applying the CSS early via [`applyCSS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#applyCss--)
- Performing the manipulation after `primaryStage.show();`
- Adding a listener to a property that is modified as it is being rendered, e.g `BoundsInParentProperty` and performing the manipulation there

In the event you run into this problem, there are several different answers and approaches to resolving it available here on SO

---

The below diagram indicates the selectors that can be used to do so:

[image]

The portion you would be interested in are the headers, the backgrounds of which I set using the below:

```
Set<Node> tableColumnHeaders = tableView.lookupAll(".column-header");
for(Node columnHeader : tableColumnHeaders){
    if(columnHeader instanceof Region){
        ((Region)columnHeader).setBackground(
                new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.GREEN, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
    }
}
```

Within this logic you could get information on the background, however as fabian advised in a comment, you should be aware that the background may not always be a color